# getting Exception while using Dataframe where clause

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, max, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to operate sample operation on **Datarame** **where** clause.

Here is my sample table data:

```
address       district
hyderabad      001
delhi          002
mumbai         003
```

Now i need to evaluate address, max(district) by using DataFrame.

The result will be like:

mumbai         003

**Workaround**:

this is the code what i tried so far..,

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.app.name", "max");
        conf.set("spark.master", "local");
        conf.set("spark.ui.port", "7077");

        SparkContext  ctx=new SparkContext(conf);       
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(ctx);
        DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load("/Users/hadoop/Downloads/SacramentocrimeJanuary2006.csv");
        //df.registerTempTable("consumer");
        //Row[] result = df.orderBy("cdatetime").select("cdatetime","address").collect();
        //DataFrame a = df.select("address","district").agg(functions.count("district"),functions.col("address")).orderBy("address");
        DataFrame b =df.select("address","district").where("district=max(district)");
        b.show();
        }
```

Here is my Exception:

```
Cannot evaluate expression: (max(input[1, IntegerType]),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable$class.genCode(Expression.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.AggregateExpression.genCode(interfaces.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$gen$2.apply(Expression.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$gen$2.apply(Expression.scala:102)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.gen(Expression.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.nullSafeCodeGen(Expression.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.defineCodeGen(Expression.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.EqualTo.genCode(predicates.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$gen$2.apply(Expression.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$gen$2.apply(Expression.scala:102)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.gen(Expression.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GeneratePredicate$.create(GeneratePredicate.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GeneratePredicate$.create(GeneratePredicate.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newPredicate(SparkPlan.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter$$anonfun$2.apply(basicOperators.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter$$anonfun$2.apply(basicOperators.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/12/09 10:50:57 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
```

Comment: you can not do the where("district=max(district)") , This expression required Sting an column and it can not assign the value the way you are trying to perform .If you will go the official doc .. peopleDs.filter($"age" > 15)
peopleDs.where($"age" > 15) ,peopleDs.where("age > 15").It can not assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

you should use “aggregation” and “join” to solve your problem。like this:

```
data.agg(max($"district").as("maxd")).as("d1").join(data.as("d2"), $"d1.maxd" === $"d2.district").select($"address",$"district").show()
```

the data is your DataFrame.It will  be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort function on dataframe & order it as descending. Then just use head function you will get required output.

Here is code sample.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("/user/userapp/sample.csv");
val a = df.sort(desc("district")).head
```

here is a output.

[image]